# Selenium IDE, take the attribute value and place it in a variable

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

HTML:
...
20
...

How do I pick up the value of "20" and put it in a variable in the Selenium IDE?

**JS:**
Command: `execute script`
Target: `return document.getElementsByClassName("timer notranslate")[0].innerText;`

**Error:** "Failed: 00:10:09 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <span class="timer notranslate" id="tmr">20</span>  
I need to take the value of "20" and add it to the variable. In Selenium IDE.